# Typescript - Type definition for a higher order function

Tags: typescript, okta

I'm using the Okta react library - `https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/tree/master/packages/okta-react` however it doesn't come with type definitions.

I've created a `.d.ts` defintion file that has `declare module "@okta/okta-react"` however this library has a higher order component used like: `import { withAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';` (https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/tree/master/packages/okta-react#withauth)

How do I write this in my definitions file?

Is this valid?

```
declare module "@okta/okta-react" {
    function withAuth(any): any
}
```

I've written an interface for the methods that `withAuth` gives like:

```
interface OktaWithAuth {
    /**
     * Returns true or false, depending on whether the user has an active access or id token.
     */
    isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean>;
....
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `withAuth` a generic function that takes a component type and returns that component type but with the props modified to remove `auth`:

```
declare module "@okta/okta-react" {
  import React from 'react'
  function withAuth<P extends { auth: OktaWithAuth }>(comp: React.ComponentType<P>): React.ComponentType<Omit<P, 'auth'>>
  interface OktaWithAuth {
      /**
       * Returns true or false, depending on whether the user has an active access or id token.
       */
      isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean>;

  }
}
```

Sample in playground: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/LAKFEsFsAcHsCcAuACASgUwIYGMUDN5ZJkByeLXE0AE3WwBtNzk8BXAO13FneQHdwiABYBBVsIA8ABWToAHonTtqAZ2QBvZJnFCAXMgDyAa0SYA6oNE7kAXwB8ACmxFo+jDkQA6AMIueSxAAVAE9odGk7AEo3Ci9fGH92INDwg0hBaQAaUm1hEjs7CCT0eDwcdEMTc0sxYQ1QZGQAegAqFobGlrR0RFZ4djVEeFYKhBZMehV0bNow5XB2AHNkHn4hHvX4ZGEK1imtoUw1TF4PcAA3CpxsdBU1MfBqbdgjJU8O5BamjvAVWvWkuBsJhFNQHNFkFJCOkphIAEawWD0LDsOwAblAoBsmLAIGcAxQAFlgvFoMgALz8Go6BwOVwaLQ6fTGUwWYT-bKwHbwKGwekqIYLZY2SIUuz1ECNci9frICTUC52dTQTxcza86A2CRNBXnQogEU45EoAzc0kU5DgsVy4nmtUlDXkgBETua4qaTWQADlYIy6uQAI6scDkaigIA)

The `Omit<P, 'auth'>` removes from `P` the `auth` property using the predefined `Omit` helper type. This will mean the returned component, will have the same props that the input component has, but without the `auth` property which is provided by `withAuth`.

Comment: Thanks - although I don't fully understand the line `function withAuth<P extends { auth: OktaWithAuth }>(comp: React.ComponentType<P>): React.ComponentType<Omit<P, 'auth'>>`
So to confirm here we have some generic `P` that will extend `OktaWithAuth`, it takes some component `comp` however this return part `React.ComponentType<Omit<P, 'auth'>>` what does that `<Omit<P, 'auth'>>` part mean?

Comment: @userMod2 Added some explanations, hope it helps.

Comment: This is really great - thanks so much for explaining!